# Iterating through multiple children in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state

I am working on a React application and would like to add an array of organizations to the state tree. Each organization can be retrieved by:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/organizations/' + org).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val();
      });
```

I am currently trying:

```
var orgs = user.organizations.map((org)=> {
  return firebase.database().ref('/organizations/' + org).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.val();
  });
});

this.setState({
  organizations: orgs,
});
```

Which is not working because the promise is not resolved before adding to state. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in these cases is to move the code that needs the snapshot *into* the callback:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/organizations/');
var promises = user.organizations.map(org => ref.child(org).once('value'));
Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots => {
    // all snapshots have loaded
    // TODO: call this.setState() with all snapshots.
})
```

Let's see if this reads better:

```
var promises = user.organizations.map(org => {
  return firebase.database().ref('/organizations/' + org).once('value')0;
});

Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots =>
  var orgs = snapshots.map(snapshot => snapshot.val());
  this.setState({
    organizations: orgs,
  })
})
```

Comment: wouldn't that only add one organization's value to `this.state.organizations`?

Comment: Ah good point. I wasn't paying that much attention. In that case you'll need a `Promise.all()`.